# Directly returning an object in a promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise, request-promise

Why would this piece of code

```
app.post('/api/v1/subscribe', (req, res) => {
  lsq.services.get('subscribe')
    .then(service => {
      method: 'POST',
      uri: `http://${service}/api/v1/demo/subscribe`,
      json: req.body,
    })
    .then(rp)
});
```

throw error

```
 uri: `http://${service}/api/v1/demo/subscribe`,
    ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

My guess is that JS considers `{` as function opening braces, not object opening braces. So, are we not allowed to directly return an object in a promise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't related to promises at all, only to the ambiguity of the fat arrow function syntax. The problem is the literal object you return is confused with a function body. Just put it between parenthesis:

```
app.post('/api/v1/subscribe', (req, res) => {
  lsq.services.get('subscribe')
    .then(service => ({
      method: 'POST',
      uri: `http://${service}/api/v1/demo/subscribe`,
      json: req.body,
    }))
    .then(rp)
});
```

Comment: Please just close as a dupe instead of answering

Comment: @Bergi I close many questions as dupe but I'm sorry, I can't be aware of **all** previous questions asked on SO

Comment: Not all of them of course, but this one is rather popular :-)

Comment: I guess I wasn't active enough recently, I hadn't seen it...

Comment: You also don't have any ES6 badge, so I guess I'm just a bit biased…